# Opencart перевод установленного шаблона

Tags: php, веб-программирование, cms, opencart

Натянул шаблон на версию opencart 2.3.0.2
В шаблоне были папки admin и catalog внутри них папки language/en-gb , скопировал папку en-gb и назвал ru-ru, как я понял языковые файлы надо переводить вручную - ок. Установил новый язык в админ панели.

После открываю сайт, и сталкиваюсь с некоторой проблемой, а именно.
Не отображаются слайдеры, не отображается боковое меню, и список товаров.
На моем шаблоне этим всем занимаются модули, как я понял их надо тоже перевести, собственно вопрос в том, как перевести модули ? и правильно ли я понял что их надо тоже переводить ? 
Я новичек в opencart поэтому сильно не пинайте, скриншоты во вложении.

[image: это версия с английским языком, как видите все ок]

[image: а это версия с русским, больше половины сайта не открылось]

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в расширении Visual Composer который устанавливал шаблон.
Зашел в раздел Visual Composer в админке, вставил нужный контент в добавленный язык, и модули начали работать.